# selenium sendkeys alternative to send emoji

Tags: vba, selenium, web, web-scraping, sendkeys

Sendkeys method does not support emojis in selenium basic so I am trying to use a workaround. The workaround I tried works in [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but does not work in the second example.

1. First example- works OK.

> `Public bot As New Selenium.Chromedriver`
>
> ```
> Public Sub Test_google_search()
>
>     Dim ele As WebElement
>     Dim myVar As String
>
>     bot.Start
>     bot.Get "https://www.google.com/"
>     Set ele = bot.FindElementByName("q")
>     myVar = "test"
>     Call MySendKeys(myVar, ele, "value")
>     bot.Quit
> End Sub
> ```

2.second sub does not work

> `Public bot As New Selenium.Chromedriver`
>
> ```
> Public Sub test(ByVal Row As Long)
> Dim Textw As String
> Dim Message As String
> Dim ele As WebElement
>
> Message = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"
> Textw = "this is a test"
>
> bot.FindElementByXPath(Message, timeout:=60000).Click
> Set ele = bot.FindElementByXPath(Message, timeout:=60000)
> Call MySendKeys(Textw, ele, "value")
> End Sub
> ```

> ```
> ''SendKeys that allow to send emoji
> Public Sub MySendKeys(ByVal myVar As String, ByVal ele As WebElement, ByVal myAttribute As String)
>     Dim attrScript As String
>     attrScript = "arguments[0].setAttribute('" & myAttribute & "','" & myVar & "')"
>     bot.ExecuteScript attrScript, ele
> End Sub
> ```

HTML:

```
 <div tabindex="-1" class="_1JAUF _2x4bz"><div class="OTBsx"
 style="visibility: visible">הקלד/י הודעה</div><div class="_2_1wd
 copyable-text selectable-text" contenteditable="true" data-tab="6"
 dir="rtl" spellcheck="true"></div></div>
```

Comment: Where are you sending it in the second example? And is a suitable destination for "text" input?

Comment: Whatsapp web  message element by full XPath.

Message= "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"

Comment: the problem is with the attribute setting because the second example there is no tag that could be used.  The syntex of attrScript should be changed in order for JavaScriptExecutor to work , not sure exactly how the syntax should be rewritten .

Comment: share the relevant html

Comment: <div class="OTBsx" style="visibility: visible;">Type message</div>

Comment: that is where you want to send the emoji?

Comment: yes, "Type message"  has no tag

Comment: ? It is a div tag

Comment: I guess, I do not know HTML too well

Comment: It is a div tag. With two attributes. It can be targeted in many ways e.g. FindElementByCss(".OTBsx")  though you may need to add other reference elements to get the right one if multiple elements exist on the page with that class and the one you want is not the first.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB1O30fR-EE&list=PLillGF-RfqbZTASqIqdvm1R5mLrQq79CU

Comment: bot.FindElementByCss(".OTBsx").Click is a syntax error.

Comment: cScript = "document.FindElementByCss(".OTBsx").value ='" & Textw & "'"  is also a syntax error

Comment: FindElementByCss is not javascript. It is selenium. If you intend to invoke custom js you will need `document.querySelector(".OTBsx").value`

Comment: `cScript = "document.querySelector('.OTBsx').value ='" & myVar & "'"  ` syntax is OK but text is not written to the element